# recursive asynchronous JavaScript for nested data structure processing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm looking to write a JavaScript function which takes the following data structure as an argument:

```
let data = [
  {value: 'a'},
  {delay: [
    {value: 'b'},
    {delay: [
      {value: 'c'}
    ]}
  ]},
  {value: 'd'}
];
```

As you can see, the data structure is an array of objects. The objects each contain a single property. Each of these properties is either a "value" with a string or a "delay" with another array of the same type as its value.

The function should print to the console each "value" string and pause for two seconds for each "delay" before processing the array of the delay in the same manner. The function should support any depth of delay nesting. The two level deep delay nesting shown above is just an example.

The output of the function to the console for the example data above should be (in this order, and only this order):

```
a
b
c
d
```

How would one write the code to implement this function?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service; it's a place to ask a _specific_ question or get help with a _specific_ problem. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is a specific question about a specific problem, namely processing nested data structures with recursive asynchronous JavaScript and promises.

Comment: I don't see a question mark, and I do see the phrase "Please write the code to implement this function"

Comment: was that what you needed ;) @user2245766

Comment: I have rephrased the posting as a question. Please see the updated version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Promises and async/await:

```js
let data = [
  {value: 'a'},
  {delay: [
    {value: 'b'},
    {delay: [
      {value: 'c'}
    ]}
  ]},
  {value: 'd'}
];

const delay = () => new Promise( res => 
  setTimeout( res, 2000) ) 

const recFn = async data =>{
  for(let obj of data){
    if(obj.value){
      console.log(obj.value)
    } else if(obj.delay){
      await delay();
      await recFn(obj.delay)
    }
  }
}

recFn(data);
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be no delay between c and d?

Comment: @heybignick I think it was a little unclear in the question, but I think you're right. I've edited my anwser. =)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea.  What you'll end up with is a `values` array that will look like 
`["a", "delay", "b", "delay", "c", "d"]`

Also, [here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heybignick/994ugeLu/5/).

```
let data = [
    {value: 'a'},
    {delay: [
      {value: 'b'},
      {delay: [
        {value: 'c'}
      ]}
    ]},
    {value: 'd'}
  ];

let values = [];

while(data.length) {
  if(typeof data[0].value !== 'undefined') {
    values.push(data[0].value);
    data.shift();
  }else {
    values.push('delay');
    var delayArray = data[0].delay; 
    data.shift();
    data = delayArray.concat(data);
  }
};

outputDelay(values);

function outputDelay(elements) {
    if(!elements.length) return false;
    if(elements[0] == "delay") {
    setTimeout(function(){
      elements.shift();
      outputDelay(elements);
    }, 2000);  
  } else {
    console.log(elements[0]);
    elements.shift();
    outputDelay(elements);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a great idea to simplify things

Comment: Thanks! It works, but not nearly as eloquent as Jose's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `async` / `await` and object destructuring, here's a more readable approach for recursively walking and printing the object:

```js
let data = [
  { value: 'a' },
  { delay: [
      { value: 'b' },
      { delay: [
          { value: 'c' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { value: 'd' }
]

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

async function walk(array) {
  for (const { value, delay } of array) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value)
    } else if (delay) {
      await sleep(1000)
      await walk(delay)
    }
  }
}

walk(data)
```